# Error while seeding via MapProxy from GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, mapproxy

We are using MapProxy to cache/seed the maps from GeoServer. Halfway through the seeding process of a layer there is an error:

> [17:17:14]  0   0.00% -41170.00000, 306838.00000, 279995.00000, 629467.00000 (0 tiles)
>   [17:17:25]  5   6.25% 30284.94505, 592657.78022, 101739.89011, 629467.00000 (1088 tiles)
>   [17:17:35]  4  12.50% 101739.89011, 592657.78022, 244649.78022, 629467.00000 (2240 tiles)
>   [17:17:46]  5  18.75% 173194.83516, 592657.78022, 244649.78022, 629467.00000 (3328 tiles)
>   [17:18:07]  3  25.00% 244649.78022, 592657.78022, 279995.00000, 629467.00000 (4544 tiles)
>   [17:18:19]  3  50.00% -41170.00000, 306838.00000, 244649.78022, 592657.78022 (5248 tiles)
>   [17:18:35]  5  51.56% 30284.94505, 521202.83516, 101739.89011, 592657.78022 (6592 tiles)
>   [17:18:51]  5  53.12% -41170.00000, 449747.89011, 30284.94505, 521202.83516 (7936 tiles)
>   [17:19:07]  5  54.69% 30284.94505, 449747.89011, 101739.89011, 521202.83516 (9280 tiles)
>   [17:20:04]  4  56.25% 101739.89011, 449747.89011, 244649.78022, 592657.78022 (10688 tiles)
>   [17:21:30]  5  57.81% 173194.83516, 521202.83516, 244649.78022, 592657.78022 (12032 tiles)
>   [17:23:07]  5  59.38% 101739.89011, 449747.89011, 173194.83516, 521202.83516 (13376 tiles)
>   [17:26:15]  5  60.94% 173194.83516, 449747.89011, 244649.78022, 521202.83516 (14720 tiles)
>   [17:29:22]  4  62.50% -41170.00000, 306838.00000, 101739.89011, 449747.89011 (16128 tiles)
>   [2019-05-23 17:30:56,165] mapproxy.source.wms - WARNING - could not retrieve WMS map: Internal HTTP error "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/spin/wms?styles=&format=image%2Fpng&height=2248&bbox=94761.8681318,442769.868132,251627.802198,599635.802198&transparent=True&layers=WegvakkenDetour&service=WMS&width=2248&request=GetMap&srs=EPSG%3A28992&version=1.1.1": timeout('timed out',)
>   An error occured. Retry in 2 seconds: SourceError('Internal HTTP error "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/spin/wms?styles=&format=image%2Fpng&height=2248&bbox=94761.8681318,442769.868132,251627.802198,599635.802198&transparent=True&layers=WegvakkenDetour&service=WMS&width=2248&request=GetMap&srs=EPSG%3A28992&version=1.1.1": timeout(\'timed out\',)',). Retries left: 100

Works when the map is directly retrieved via a browser by using the following link:

> "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/spin/wms?styles=&format=image%2Fpng&height=2248&bbox=94761.8681318,442769.868132,251627.802198,599635.802198&transparent=True&layers=WegvakkenDetour&service=WMS&width=2248&request=GetMap&srs=EPSG%3A28992&version=1.1.1"

There are no errors in the logs of GeoServer or MapProxy

I tried increasing the JVM heap space for tomcat in which GeoServer is deployed.

I tried increasing the rendering time and memory on the WMS page in GeoServer dashboard.

Our MapProxy+GeoServer setup works perfectly fine with 20 other layers but for this one layer it gives this error. How can I figure this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increasing the MapProxy Timeout value via globals.http.client_timeout parameter helped me solve this issue.

Comment: Could you provide a working configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following globals configuration in the mapproxy.yaml:

```
globals:
  http:
    client_timeout: 86400
```

For http requests the timeout is then set to 86400 seconds.